# Does EF Core support an abstract base entity which is generic?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

I remember there were problems with generic entities in previous EF. How about EF Core? I can't find docs related to this matter.

For example:

```
public abstract class Parent<TEntity> {
  public int EntityId { get; set; }
  public TEntity Entity { get; set; }
}

public class Child : Parent<Foo> {
}

public class OtherChild : Parent<Bar> {
}


// config for child entities includes this:
config.HasKey(c => c.EntityId);
```

Though this throws stating that child entities do not define a primary key, when they clearly do!

*I can fix this by making `Parent` non-generic.*

Are there official docs for this? Am I doing something wrong, or is this the expected behavior?

Comment: Did you include `Foo` and `Bar` into the EF model? With ef-core 1.1.0 this will work.

Comment: @GertArnold Doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can use this model in ef-core 1.1.0:

```
public abstract class Parent<TEntity>
{
    public int EntityId { get; set; }
    public TEntity Entity { get; set; }
}

public class Child : Parent<Foo>
{
}

public class OtherChild : Parent<Bar>
{
}

public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

With this mapping in the context:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder mb)
{
    mb.Entity<Child>().HasKey(a => a.EntityId);
    mb.Entity<Child>().HasOne(c => c.Entity).WithMany().HasForeignKey("ParentId");
    mb.Entity<OtherChild>().HasKey(a => a.EntityId);
    mb.Entity<OtherChild>().HasOne(c => c.Entity).WithMany().HasForeignKey("ParentId");
}
```

Which leads to this fantastic model:

[image]

Comment: How did you generate that image?

Comment: Oh, just in Sql Server Management Studio, under a database: Database Diagrams.